# How to implement MapThread with basic list mapping?

Tags: algorithm, list, wolfram-mathematica, tex

Mathematica has a function [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html) that behaves like this:

```
MapThread[ f , { {a,b,c} , {d,e,f} } ]
-> { f[a,d] , f[b,e] , f[c,f] }
```

I'd like to implement this in TeX, which has very primitive programming facilities. I've basic facilities for iterating over lists, but no logical indexing into them. Given this restriction, is there an algorithm for looping synchronously though multiple lists?

I could write something like the following: (pseudocode)

```
ii = 0; jj = 0;
for elem1 in list1
  ii = ii+1
  for elem2 in list2
    jj = jj+1
    if ii == jj
      return ( elem1 , elem2 )
    fi
  end
end
```

but it seems terribly inefficient. Note that the big restriction is that I can't access elements of lists numerically, so something like the following is too "high level":

```
for ii = 1:length(list1)
  func ( list1(ii) , list2(ii) )
end
```

The reason this restriction is in place is that in order to implement `list1(ii)` I'd need to write something like the following in the first place:

```
jj = 0
for elem1 in list1
  jj = jj+1
  if ii=jj
    return elem1
  fi
end
```

Or is the inefficient case probably the best I'll be able to do with such a primitive language?

Comment: Can you do the equivalent of First[] and Rest[] on these lists, and test if they have length zero? In that case it's not so hard; otherwise your N^2 trick is probably the best solution without crufting together your own macros to do manipulate the lists.

Comment: First[] and Rest[] are possible, yes. Ah, I think I see where you're going with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudocode, as long as you can test whether a list is empty, you can do it like so:

```
while (list1 is not empty) and (list2 is not empty)
  x1 = first(list1);
  x2 = first(list2);
  list1 = rest(list1);
  list2 = rest(list2);

  func(x1, x2);
end while
```

It's still not going to win any beauty contests, but it'll get the job done without being crushingly inefficient.